# When should I return HTTP Status Code 500 (Internal Server Error) from REST application to client?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes, internal-server-error, http-response-codes, http-status-code-500

I have seen people using the HTTP code 500 as a generic error code for all kind of error cases (server errors, http errors, code exceptions, expected record not found in DB, time-out exceptions etc). However I have also read and heard that this code 500 should only be used in case of errors originating from the *application server* (JBoss in my case), and NOT *application* itself  i.e. not for code-exceptions or invalid passwords or DB-record-not-found cases. So, when should we return HTTP Status Code 500 from a REST service method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the HTTP spec:

> The 5xx (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the requested method. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. A user agent SHOULD display any included representation to the user. These response codes are applicable to any request method.

<sup>**Original:** https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.6.6</sup>

Note that from the protocol point of view, it doesn't matter whether it's the application server or something running *inside* the application server.